# To fix an error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'convert'

Tags: python, numpy, deconvolution

I applied Image deconvolution using an unsupervised wiener algorithm and increased the sharpness and contrast on a specific dataset. But I faced an error while compiling the code. It shows **AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'convert'.** How to fix it? My code is given below -

```
import cv2
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import io, color, restoration, img_as_float
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance

all_img = glob.glob('input/*.png')
other_dir = 'output/'

for img_id, img_path in enumerate(all_img):
    img = img_as_float(io.imread(img_path,0))

    def gkern(kernlen=21, nsig=2):   
        lim = kernlen//2 + (kernlen % 2)/2
        x = np.linspace(-lim, lim, kernlen+1)
        kern1d = np.diff(st.norm.cdf(x))
        kern2d = np.outer(kern1d, kern1d)
        return kern2d/kern2d.sum()

    psf = gkern(5,3)   

    deconvolved, _ = restoration.unsupervised_wiener(img, pdf)

    # Applied Sharpness and contrast
    enhancer_object = ImageEnhance.Contrast(deconvolved)
    out = enhancer_object.enhance(1.4)
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(out)
    enhanced_im = enhancer.enhance(8.0)  
    enhanced_cv_im = np.array(enhanced_im)

    cl2 = cv2.resize(enhanced_cv_im, (512,512), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    plt.imsave(f"output/unsupervised_wiener_{img_id}.png", cl2, cmap='gray')
```

**It shows the error-**

```
runfile('C:/Users/Junaed/.spyder-py3/unsupervised_wiener.py', wdir='C:/Users/Junaed/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Junaed\.spyder-py3\unsupervised_wiener.py", line 37, in <module>
    enhancer_object = ImageEnhance.Contrast(deconvolved)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'convert'
```

Comment: can you post the whole error?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: from the error message I suspect that you used a numpy array where an image object was expected. But without the whole traceback this is just speculation. Please add the whole output.

Comment: `How to fix it?` Instead of passing a numpy.ndarray for the argument, pass the object type that the method/function expects.

Comment: Is the indentation in your post correct? Is `gkern` iteratively defined ***in*** the for loop?

Comment: @wwii ok, I also attached the screenshot of my error part. plz tell what should I do to fix this

Comment: @Sarvagya Gupta, yes I already posted, plz check this.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @wwii (Is gkern iteratively defined in the for loop?) - yes, I want to apply image deconvolution on multiple images and it still works without sharpness and contrast part. But when I added sharpness+ contrast portion, it will be given an error like above.

Comment: [PIL.ImageEnhance.Contrast](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageEnhance.html#PIL.ImageEnhance.Contrast) takes an Image not an ndarray.

Comment: @ I already add this, but it shows `name 'PIL' not defined.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageEnhance.Contrast() is expecting a PIL image which it can run image.convert on but you passed it a numpy array. To convert to PIL  you can do this

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy 

im = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(deconvolved))
```

Comment: i add this, it will shows a message that name 'PIL' is not defined. But i already added this.

Comment: `deconvolved, _ = restoration.unsupervised_wiener(img, psf)
im = PIL.Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(deconvolved))
enhancer_object = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
out = enhancer_object.enhance(1.4)
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(out)
enhanced_im = enhancer.enhance(8.0)  
enhanced_cv_im = np.array(enhanced_im)` After edit my code part

Comment: You need to import PIL for use by pip installing Pillow then you can import PIL

Comment: I already used that pillow library before post the question. I use like this - `from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance`

Comment: Okay then just import Image as well from PIL and use Image.fromarray() instead

Comment: it works, but it returns multiple black images. but without adding sharpness and contrast portion, it still works